# how to fix Unable to resolve dependency for 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0.'

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, build.gradle, circleimage

Why doesn't this dependency

`implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'`

sync with my project ?

Comment: There are several possible reasons: you don't have network connectivity, the artifact does not exist, you did not configure the repository where it is located, ...

Comment: Please kindly check if your studio is in Offline mode or not if yes then disable Offline mode and then try again.

Comment: can you show your build.gradle?

Comment: you are probably missing the mavenCentral repository

Answer (score 0):

Add `mavenCentral`, `jcenter` and `jitpack` in `repositories` in `build.gradle` file

like this:

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
 maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```